# Find matching records of two different tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in one of them a seller saves a record for a product he is selling. and in another table buyers save what they need to buy.

I need to get a list of user ids (uid field) from buyers table which matches a specific product on sales table. this is what I have written:

```
select n.[uid] 
from needs n 
  left join ads(getdate()) a 
         on n.mid=a.mid 
        and a.[year] between n.from_year and n.to_year 
        and a.price between n.from_price and n.to_price 
        and n.[uid]=a.[uid] 
        and a.pid=n.pid
```

Well I need to use a where clause to eliminate those records which doesn't match. as I think all of these conditions are defined with `ON` must be defined with a where clause. but joining needs at least one `ON` clause. may be I shouldn't join two tables? what can I do?

Comment: Please use a `INNER JOIN` and see if that meets your requirements. In order words, delete the word `LEFT` from your query.

Comment: greattttt. I have always been curious about the differences of left and inner join. This was what I was looking for.

Comment: I will elaborate in an answer. :)

Comment: please add it as answer. so I can choose it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an important difference between `LEFT JOIN` and `JOIN`, or more accurately `OUTER` and `INNER` joins respectively.

Inner joins require that both sides of the join match. In other words, if you:

- had a table representing People
- you had another table representing Automobiles
- and each automobile had a PersonId
- and joined these tables using `ON` with the PersonId

using `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN` would return all people, even those without automobiles. `INNER JOIN` only returns the people with vehicles.

This article may help: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html